# datepicker выбор даты начиная с завтрашнего дня

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Как в `datepicker` сделать чтобы выбирать дату можно только начиная с завтрашнего дня? То есть, нельзя выбрать сегодняшнюю и прошедшие даты

Comment: В каком `datepicker`? Их сотни всяких разных. Если речь идёт о стандартном, то у него есть атрибуты `min` и `max`?

Comment: @vihtor bootstrap-datepicker.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно сконфигурировать datepicker параметром [startDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate).

Comment: datesDisabled: new Date() так получилось